# UITableView custom cell IBOutlets are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a class which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and I have also created an `xib` file for the same.

In the `xib` file I am adding a `UITableViewCell` and then giving it an identifier "ChatCell" and then in my class I am trying to use this custom cell like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier =  @"ChatCell";
ChatCustomCell *cell = (ChatCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

In the class I have provided an `IBOutlet` of `UIlabel` and connected it to one of the `UILabel` I have created in the `xib` but when ever the cell gets created the `UILabel` stays `nil`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you register the nib file in ViewController?

Comment: No I did not but I believe I do not need to

Comment: if you are using storyboard to create prototype cell you don't need to register the nib else you should

Comment: I am using the xib file

Comment: You can design multiple cells as prototype cells directly in the table view. An extra nib is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register your Custom Xib file in your ViewController first.

From [Apple Docs on registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:):

> call this method or the registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method
>   to tell the table view how to create new cells. If a cell of the
>   specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the table view uses
>   the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.

E.g. Write this line in your `viewDidLoad`, after setting tableView delegate and dataSource:

```
[yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChatCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ChatCell"];
```

If you don't, your TableView won't be able to load the Cell Nib file, which would result in nil IBOutlets of Cell.

Comment: Thank you this works I was trying this before too but maybe was wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Avinash : use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath: ] for cell reuse. this is new API for not nil return of cell.

Answer (score 3):

for your xib cell may be it returns nil for your cell, write this code may be it helps you.

```
ChatCustomCell *cell = (ChatCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```